# Julia | How to perform a linear regression on a TimeArray dataset

Tags: statistics, time-series, regression, julia, linear-regression

I have a `TimeArray` type dataset, and I would like to perform a linear regression. However, it appears that julia does not currently support regression methods for `TimeArray` types.

I can download the data as a `DataFrame` instead of a `TimeArray` and use the `GLM` package, but the `TimeArray` timestamp is quite useful for other analyses later on. I would like to perform a linear regression directly on the `TimeArray` dataset.

**Edit 1:** A simple example is given below:

```
julia> using TimeSeries

       dates = collect(Date(1999,1,1):Date(1999,1,31))

       # Dependent variable
       y  = TimeArray(dates, rand(length(dates)))

       # Explanatory variables 
       x1 = TimeArray(dates, rand(length(dates))) # Explanatory variable 1
       x2 = TimeArray(dates, rand(length(dates))) # Explanatory variable 2
       x  = rename(merge(x1,x2), ["x1", "x2"])    # Merge x1 and x2 into a single TimeArray

       # Linear regression
       coefs = linreg(x, y) # Yields a method error since linreg does not support the TimeArray type.
```

Has anyone found a solution or workaround for this problem?

Comment: Just my 2¢: if you post a minimal example with data and what you envision / code you've tried that doesn't work, you're more likely to get people who might want to tinker and figure it out. As it is now, the only way someone will answer this as a general question is if *someone* encountered and solved the *exact* same problem in the recent past, which is much less likely.

Comment: Also, why can't you do your analysis on the DataFrame version and simply save the timestamps for your later analyses anyway?

Comment: See here for additional details for implementing Tasos' suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @g.costa: the TimeSeries package seems broken on the dev version of julia. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using v 0.4.6 of julia, and the latest version of TimeSeries.jl from GitHub.

Comment: The linear regression only uses the values, not the timestamps, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is not what you want, but `coefs = linreg(x.values,y.values)` seems to work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TimeArray` type seems to have a `.values` field you can use to obtain the values associated with the array in the right order. So you can perform your linear regression with:

```
coefs = linreg(x.values,y.values)
```

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous you could even define a new method for linreg for the TimeArray type that uses the .values field :)